# Error al pasar GUID desde cliente a servidor Angular-asp .net

Tags: c#, angular, mvc

Estoy intentando pasar un parámetro `idEmpresa` Guid desde Angular al servidor. Al mandarle el parámetro desde angular puedo observar que lo manda bien aunque el servidor lo recibe siempre a `0`. Adjunto el código:

Angular:

```
eliminarAdministrador(idEmpresa: Guid){
    return this._httpClient.post<boolean>(this.URL + 'Administrador/borrarAdministrador', idEmpresa)
    .subscribe(resultado => {
      if (resultado) {
        alert('Administrador eliminado correctamente.');
        //ir a datos empresa.
      } else {
        alert('Error al eliminar');
      }
    }, (error) => alert(error.message + 'Error conexion?'));
  }
```

Servidor C#:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("borrarAdministrador")]
        public async Task<bool> borrar(Guid idEmpresa, CancellationToken token)
        {
            using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
            {
                try
                {
                    var idInt =  _context.Empresa.Where(m => m.IdEmpresa == idEmpresa).Select(i => i.Id);
                    var empreAdmin = await _context.EmpresaAdministrador.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IdEmpresa.Equals(idInt));
                    var adminDB = await _context.Administrador.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id ==empreAdmin.IdAdministrador);
                    _context.EmpresaAdministrador.Remove(empreAdmin);
                    _context.Administrador.Remove(adminDB);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(token);
                    transaction.Commit();

                    return true;
                }
                catch
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();`introducir el código aquí`
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Conseguiste solucionar tu duda?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el campo IdEmpresa lo estás pasando en el Payload de la petición. Para recuperarlo tienes que especificar, en el parámetro, que viene en el body (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). Quedaría algo así:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("borrarAdministrador")]
    public async Task<bool> borrar([FromBody] Guid idEmpresa, CancellationToken token)
    {
        using (var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
        {
            try
            {
                var idInt =  _context.Empresa.Where(m => m.IdEmpresa == idEmpresa).Select(i => i.Id);
                var empreAdmin = await _context.EmpresaAdministrador.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.IdEmpresa.Equals(idInt));
                var adminDB = await _context.Administrador.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id ==empreAdmin.IdAdministrador);
                _context.EmpresaAdministrador.Remove(empreAdmin);
                _context.Administrador.Remove(adminDB);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync(token);
                transaction.Commit();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                transaction.Rollback();`introducir el código aquí`
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Espero que te sirva.